# Should I accept an answer that isn't 100% what I expected?

Tags: discussion

I have a relatively [old question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4682/allow-users-to-select-among-various-default-images-while-creating-their-profile-i) laying in DA, and I feel bad about it because I haven't accepted any answer yet. My dilemma is that I don't want to accept one of the answers as they're not exactly what I expected (and I'm not sure there's a solution that doesn't involve writing some custom code) but also I don't wan't to see my [accept rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work) being affected by it.

Should I accept one answer?
Should I close/delete my question?
Should I answer it saying I'm writing a bunch of code even if to the date I haven't written anything?
Should I not care about accept rate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A question without an accepted answer is not necessarily a question that should not exist, unless it is an off-topic question.

Closing the question, or deleting it, is not ideal: Somebody might have the same issue and would benefit from seeing at least what might work, even if the answers so far haven't been a complete solution.

Unless the accept rate is very low (for example, less than 40%), don't worry about it.

If you found a solution to your problem, even if your final solution is based on the other answers, leave it as an answer and accept that. In this way, people who find your question will know what worked for you.

If you really want to get a better answer, consider [offering a bounty](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty).

Answer (score 1):

That question is relevant and probably hasn't been answered yet because it is before its time. If you still feel you need to know the answer, try editing and rewriting it.